# Matlab function that does (0:N-1)/N * M

Tags: matlab

I'd like to generate 20 uniformly spaced angles. Here are two not-so-neat solutions:

```
n = 20;

% unnecessary line
angles = linspace(0,2*pi,n+1);
angles = angles(1:end-1)

% intention unclear
angles = (0:n-1)/n * 2*pi
```

Is there a `linspace`-like function that does this in a better way?

Comment: I think that you doing well, this is the way. If you very want you can use one-line linspace like that: `angles=linspace(0,2*pi-(2*pi/n),n)`

Comment: What is wrong with angles=linspace(0,2*pi,n)? Or do you want n angles including 0 but not including 2*pi? In which case your two line (%unnecessary line) solution may be optimal.

Comment: I actually think that what you've labelled "intention unclear" is the clearest of all of these (to any with a modicum of Matlab experience). The rest frankly seem a tad bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

`linspace` is written in Matlab (i.e. it's not a built-in function). You could easily modify its code so as not to generate the last element, and save that as another function.

In fact, if you see `linspace`'s code you'll notice that the last element has to be appended specifically. So your hunch was right: it's more "natural" not to include the last element.

In the code below I include the modified three lines and the original ones to compare.

```
function y = linspace2(d1, d2, n)

if nargin == 2
    n = 100;
end
n = double(n+1); %// modified line
%// Originally: n = double(n);
n1 = floor(n)-1;
vec = 0:n-2;
if isinf(d2 - d1) 
    y = d1 + (d2/n1).*vec - (d1/n1).*vec; %// modified line
    %// Originally: y = [d1 + (d2/n1).*vec - (d1/n1).*vec, d2];
else
    y = d1 + (vec.*(d2-d1)/n1); %// modified line
    %// Originally: y = [d1 + (vec.*(d2-d1)/n1), d2];
end
```